# LongBox in GWT - remove thousand delimiter formatting

Tags: gwt

I want to format a number in GWT LongBox For exmple: I have a number : 2,134, I don't want show thousand delimiter(,) here and want to show like 2134.

How can we implement this in GWT ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to implement your own `LongBox` widget:

```
public class MyLongBox extends ValueBox<Long> {
  public MyLongBox() {
    super(Document.get().createTextInputElement(), 
          new AbstractRenderer<Long>() {
            public String render(Long l) {
              return l == null ? "" : l.toString();
            }
          },
          LongParser.instance());
  }
}

MyLongBox lb = new MyLongBox();
lb.setValue(2134l);
RootPanel.get().add(lb);
```

But if you cannot change your ui, you could change the global `decimalFormat` variable.

```
private static native void changeCachedDecimalFormat(NumberFormat f) /*-{
  @com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat::cachedDecimalFormat = f;
}-*/;

changeCachedDecimalFormat(NumberFormat.getFormat("###0"));

LongBox lb = new LongBox();
lb.setValue(2134l);
RootPanel.get().add(lb);
```

Comment: No. I have LongBox. If I set value on this, say for eg: 2134 by calling box.setValue(2134). My box on UI shows it as 2,134. I want it to show as 2134 (without comma).

Comment: ah ok I misunderstood your question. Is it an option to change the type of your class by another one (ie: MyLongBox.java) ?

Comment: Violator pattern is not Evil, think in it like an option for certain cases like reflection does in JVM. Many things in gwt core, gin, gQuery etc relay in it. I also prefer the first solution though.

Comment: I am new user, the system is saying "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :(, so I cant mark it answer.

Comment: actually you havent mark it, you have to mark the tick if this response is the solution to your question, proly you voted up instead . Anyway, stackoverflow is not intuitive at first.

Comment: Oh yes, I did it now. Thanks Manolo.